# Is it possible to make a Facebook desktop application in Java without using a servlet?

Tags: java, facebook, desktop-application, restfb

Is it possible to make a Facebook desktop application in Java without using a servlet?

I am developing a Facebook desktop application. I am very close to completion, but a problem comes in getting an access token.

I successfully opened a browser through my Java code, but I can't read the URL of the web browser. I don't want to use a servlet.

Comment: yes it' possible.follow this example all user need to verify themself and need to enter authorization code in your application.https://github.com/fernandezpablo85/scribe-java/blob/master/src/test/java/org/scribe/examples/FacebookExample.java

Comment: Please ask your questions politely: "just answer in yes or no" - no need for that nonsense.

Comment: Of course. An API is an API. I'm updating your title to be actually useful.

Comment: @DaveNewton My reading of the OP's question he is not using the API but controlling a browser using Java.

Comment: @leftbrain Oh. That's even weirder then.

Comment: @Umesh Awasthi
Thanx buddy ur post reaaly helps me.
It just pull me out of a dark path.

Comment: @leftbrain.
sorry for ur reading. But actually i dont want to do anything like controolling browser with java. Net is full of such codes.

Comment: @dave Newton.
Thanx for updating my title.
Yeah u r right an api is api.I can get access token for FB by providing some redirect url. but i dnt want to make a web app.
I just want to make a simple java app.
Now Scribe is the soln for this.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to do that, check out the [Authentication](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) documentation, the part you are most interested in is titled *Desktop Apps*, and it says:

> Our OAuth 2.0 implementation does not include explicit desktop app
>   support. However, if your desktop app can embed a web browser (most
>   desktop frameworks such as .NET, AIR and Cocoa support embedding
>   browsers), you can use the client-side flow with one modification: a
>   specific redirect_uri.

You can read more and see exactly how there.